# "No CAPCHAs" message. (This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, recaptcha, captcha

I added google recaptcha to my reactJs project. I added all the domains that I want the recaptcha work in include 'localhost'.
The recaptcha worked for two 2 days but suddenly I got grey box with caption "This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue".

How can I fix it? By the way, I an the site owner.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIqKH.png)

Comment: did you find the issue

Comment: Hey, yes I solved it.
It happened after I added to index.html those line:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src https://docs.google.com" />`

So for now I removed it and it work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by removing contents in Content-Security-Policy in Realm Settings > Security Defenses > Headers. For my case it worked. I think this would help although this is not right solution.